# JProfiler Netbeans plugin doesn't appear to be available

Tags: netbeans-8, jprofiler

I shut down Netbeans 8.02, installed JProfiler 9, selected the option to integrate with Netbeans 8, and was told the plugin had installed correctly. However, when I start Netbeans with a Java project, I can't see jProfiler anywhere (it's not on the Profile menu).

Any help with this gratefully received.

Comment: I don't have any problems with the integration. Does the file %APPDATA%\Netbeans\8.0.2\modules\com-jprofiler-integrations-netbeans.jar exist?

Comment: No it doesn't. The folder is actually 8.0 rather than 8.0.2, but I'm guessing that is correct.

Comment: Just spotted the problem though... I selected the wrong folder when integrating (didn't go to the config folder) - doh!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.
Environment: NetBeans 8.1, Ubuntu 14.

1) Follow JProfiler instructions to integrate NetBeans IDE.

2) JProfiler puts a message that plugin was installed.

3) Start NetBeans, choose Tools->Plugins.

4) Select Downloaded tab click Add Plugins.

5) Assuming that you downloaded netbeans6-jprofiler.nbm to 
`<install_dir>/.netbeans/8.1/config/update/download/`
you will see the netbeans6-jprofiler.nbm in the list.

6) Click Install.